# How can you populate a WTForms FieldList after the validate_on_submit() block?

Tags: forms, flask, wtforms, fieldlist

There is a real lack of documentation on how to work with WTForms' FieldList. So thanks to the internet I've been able to hack together the following:

Form:

```
class BranchForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', validators = [Required()])
    equipment = FieldList(SelectField('Equipment', validators=[Required()], coerce=int,
        choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Equipment.query.all()]))
    mod = FieldList(StringField('Method of Delivery', validators = [Optional()]))
```

View:

```
def edit_branch(id):
    branch = Branch.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    #populate data_in to be used by BranchForm
    data_in = []
    for eq_obj in branch.equipment_assoc:
        data_in.append(('equipment', eq_obj.equipment.id))
        data_in.append(('mod', eq_obj.mod))

    editform = BranchForm(data=MultiDict(data_in))

    if editform.validate_on_submit():
        branch.name = editform.name.data

        db.session.add(branch)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/admin/branches/' + str(branch.id))

    editform.name.data = branch.name

    return render_template("branch_edit.html",
        title="Edit Branch",
        branch = branch,
        editform = editform)
```

What's throwing me off is that everywhere else that I've used a WTForm Form and populated the fields with data from my db (like for edit forms), I've had to populate these form fields after the form.validate_on_submit() block, because if not, then the form will never update as whatever is submitted is immediately overwritten.

> See "editform.name.data = branch.name" (this is how I've always done it)

From every example I've found online about populating a FieldList, it apparently must be done during instantiation, but the form has to be instantiated before the validate_on_submit() as well because validate_on_submit() is a method of the form object.

> See "editform = BranchForm(data=MultiDict(data_in))" (this is how I've seen FieldLists populated in all the examples I've seen.)

How can I go about populating my form with its field lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so a buddy helped me figure this one out. Here's what I ended up with:

Form:

```
class BranchForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', validators = [Required()])
    equipment = FieldList(SelectField('Equipment', validators=[Required()], coerce=int,
        choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Equipment.query.all()]))
    mod = FieldList(StringField('Method of Delivery', validators = [Optional()]))

    def populate_assoc(self, branch_obj):
        i = 0
        branch_obj.name = self.name.data
        for assoc_obj in branch_obj.equipment_assoc:
            assoc_obj.equipment_id = self.equipment[i].data
            assoc_obj.mod = self.mod[i].data
            i += 1
```

View:

```
def edit_branch(id):
    branch = Branch.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        editform = BranchForm()

        if editform.validate_on_submit():
            editform.populate_assoc(branch)

            db.session.add(branch)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect('/admin/branches/' + str(branch.id))

    #populate data_in to be used 
    data_in = []
    for eq_obj in branch.equipment_assoc:
        data_in.append(('equipment', eq_obj.equipment.id))
        data_in.append(('mod', eq_obj.mod))

    editform = BranchForm(data=MultiDict(data_in))
    editform.name.data = branch.name

    return render_template("branch_edit.html",
        title="Edit Branch",
        branch = branch,
        editform = editform)
```

The trick was really to step away from using **form.validate_on_submit()** as my logic separator, since it relies on the form object. His idea was to use the **if request.method == 'POST':** for this purpose. This way I can instantiate my form in two different ways. One gets populated for display, the other is only instantiated if the request method is POST, thus retaining the information submitted in the form.

To finish the job I added the populate_assoc method to my form class so that I can easily place the information from the form into my association model.

Comment: I didn't try your code, as I just came across this while looking for something else.  But I upvoted because you have the right idea with using the `request.method`!

Comment: I'm confused about this line "for assoc_obj in branch_obj.equipment_assoc:"

What is equipment_assoc? @chockomonkey Can you explain this for me if you get a chance! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WtForms has a populate_obj() method. Maybe that's what you're after?

```
def edit_branch(id):
    branch = Branch.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    editform = BranchForm(obj=branch)
    if editform.validate_on_submit():
        editform.populate_obj(branch)

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect('/admin/branches/' + str(branch.id))

    return render_template("branch_edit.html",
        title="Edit Branch",
        branch = branch,
        editform = editform)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I believe that's the opposite direction than I'm after. I'm trying to populate my form with data from my model object, rather than populate my model object with data from my form.

Comment: I think this line in the answer does that: `editform = BranchForm(obj=branch)`

Comment: @PauloBu Yes it does, but that only works before the if validate_on_submit(): block. I'm looking for a way to populate BranchForm after instantiation.